# Error when trying to extract tar file: You must specify one of the `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label' options

Tags: linux, tar

While I am trying to extract cmake i am getting error:

`tar - zxvf cmake-3.4.0.tar.gz`

```
tar: You must specify one of the `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label'  options
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the **blank space** between `-` and `z`:

```
tar -zxvf cmake-3.4.0.tar.gz
```

This should work.

Comment: You can even omit `-` and `z` and just use `tar xvf cmake-3.4.0.tar.gz`.

Comment: You can but those options are meaningful, so it depends on what you exactly want to do.